# Jackson object mapping - map incoming JSON field to protected property in base class

Tags: java, json, rest, inheritance, jackson

We use Jersey/Jackson for our REST application. Incoming JSON strings get mapped to the @Entity objects in the backend by Jackson to be persisted.

The problem arises from the base class that we use for all entities. It has a protected id property, which we want to exchange via REST as well so that when we send an object that has dependencies, hibernate will automatically fetch these dependencies by their ids.

Howevery, Jackson does not access the setter, even if we override it in the subclass to be public. We also tried using @JsonSetter but to no avail. Probably Jackson just looks at the base class and sees ID is not accessible so it skips setting it...

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractPersistable<PK extends Serializable> implements Persistable<PK> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private PK id;

    public PK getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(final PK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Subclasses:

```
public class A extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    private String name;
}

public class B extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    private A a;

    private int value;

    // getter, setter

    // make base class setter accessible
    @Override
    @JsonSetter("id")
    public void setId(Long id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }
}
```

Now if there are some As in our database and we want to create a new B via the REST resource:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional
public Response create(B b) {
    if (b.getA().getId() == null) 
        cry();
}
```

with a JSON String like this `{"a":{"id":"1","name":"foo"},"value":"123"}`.

**The incoming B will have the A reference but without an ID.**

---

Is there any way to tell Jackson to either ignore the base class setter or tell it to use the subclass setter instead?

I've just found out about `@JsonTypeInfo` but I'm not sure this is what I need or how to use it.

Thanks for any help!

---

**edit**

StaxMan has me worrying I am missing something here, so I'll add my servlet configuration as this is the only other point I can think of where anything might go wrong, if my described behavior should actually be possible without adding an XML annotation to the setter (as described in my answer):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>path.to.rest.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I think you may need one more setting to enable "POJO mapping", since it is not the default one used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, found the solution already:

Have to use `@XmlElement(name="id")` on all overriding ID setters:

```
@XmlElement(name="id")
public void setId(Long id) {
    super.setId(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it should work as is. Jackson serializer looks at actual runtime class (which includes all base class properties), and should see getter ("getId()").
So something else is going on.

Based on solution, I am wondering if you might not be using Jackson POJO based mapping, but something else...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But getId is not the problem. SetId is. Im trying to save incoming Ids to a POJO where setId is a protected method in the base class and thus in accessible from outside of the subclass. So really the only way is to increase setId visibility to the subclass. But for some reason jackson does not pick up on that.

Comment: Protected modifier is not problematic for setters: Jackson will use Reflection and it can easily both detect non-public setters (which is done by default -- unlike with getters, where only `public` ones are auto-detected) as well as call it. This is why I am puzzled about your problem.

Comment: Now I am puzzled too. If you say this should work, why doesn't it? The setup is as described. Could it be some kind of setting that I did unintentionally? I'll add my servlet configuration to the question. Other than that I don't think there's any place where I influenced Jackson's behavior..